# Как указать ширину виджета для размещения его в список с 2-мя колонками?

Tags: java, android, width, gridlayoutmanager

Я создаю  RecyclerView. Указываю для него GridLayoutManeger (вертикальный, 2 колонки). Пишу адаптер для RecyclerView. Создаю макет для включения в адаптер.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewPerson"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPerson"
        android:src="@drawable/im1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Я хочу чтобы размер этого макета по ширине был равен половине ширины экрана. Я указал в макете ширину равную 140dp. Для моего смартфона это подходит, но для других уже не подойдёт. Как поступить в данной ситуации. Как получить виджет (для адаптера RecyclerView) который имеет ширину равную половине ширины экрана?

Comment: Нужно указать для CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @Style-7 ваш совет решил проблему по определению ширины виджета. Спасибо. Но тут появилась другая проблема о которой я сразу не подумал - какую высоту указывать для CardView? Все картинки (ImageView расположены на CardView) имеют соотношений высоты к ширине 1*1,5(портретная ориентация). Теперь я не знаю какую указывать высоту для CardView? Если я указываю match_parent, то CardView растягивается на весь экран, если wrap_content, то сверху и снизу много пустого места (видимо это высота несжатой картинки). Подскажите, как правильно указать высоту? Она должна быть равна ширине * 1.5

Comment: тут много вариантов, из простых указывать фиксированную высоту из ресурса а сам ресурс разный в зависимости от экрана (values-hdpi, values-xhdpi, и т.п.) в ImageView можно указать android:scaleType="centerCrop", можно и по сложнее писать свой GridLayoutManager но у меня тут нет опыта